# Drupal + page fragment caching

Tags: drupal, caching

our drupal site has some user specific content. When we enable page caching the whole page is being cached. Isn't it possible to cache only fragments of the page. Or specify which fragments not to cache? Or even specify which pages not to cache. This way we can remove some stuff from the caches when logged in. Or don't use the cached versions when logged in.

I found this website already but it doesn't seem to work:
http://www.jpstacey.info/blog/2009/03/03/how-to-not-cache-a-particular-drupal-page

But this doesn't seem to work.

kind regards,
Daan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I second Ran Bar-Ziks suggestion of putting the 'not to be cached' data in a separate block and set that block to `BLOCK_NO_CACHE`, as it is the simplest solution.

If that is not possible, you can disable caching of specific pages, but contrary to the suggestion from the link you posted, I'd do this by preventing the page from getting cached in the first place (rather than removing the cache entry afterwards).

To do this, you can manipulate the global cache config setting temporarily on the page in question:

```
// Disable caching for this request cycle
$GLOBALS['conf']['cache'] = FALSE;
```

Where you put this code depends on the pages you want to exclude from caching:

- If it is a custom node type coming from your own module, you'd put it in `hook_view`.
- If you want to do this for a node type coming from other modules, you can put it in 'view' operation part on a `hook_nodeapi()` implementation.
  ** This would also also work for individual nodes, if you add a check for the node id before disabling the cache.
- If you need to do this based on paths, you could put it in a `hook_init()` implementation, checking for the path (or path alias) to decide whether to disable caching or not.

It should be obvious that you need to clear caches first for any of these approaches to work, as they depend on preventing the page from being cached at all. They will not remove an already paged entry from the cache.

Comment: For removing specific pages or paths from being cached, there is the CacheExlude module (http://drupal.org/project/cacheexclude), which won't require coding.

Comment: @jhedstrom: Good hint - the module uses exactly the approach suggested in option 3 (path and pathalias matching in hook_init).

Comment: I wrote the content at the link he posted. Two years of experience convinces me that your way is considerably better in most situations, and I've edited my old post to reference here! The only thing I'd change to your code fragment is to use "global $conf; $conf['cache'] = ... " as that's more Drupalish and matches how variable_get() itself is laid out.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the data that you don't want to be cached in block and use BLOCK_NO_CACHE to prevent this block from caching. It is very simple thing to do and explained in drupal.api: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.module/constant/BLOCK_NO_CACHE/6

Comment: Except that caching modules like Boost will cache the entire page.

Comment: +1 - Putting the non cache data in a non cache block would be the easiest approach. As for preventing caching of specific pages, I'll add a separate answer.

Comment: @Kevin: Boost takes a completely different approach to caching, thus circumventing many of the build in cache settings of Drupal. So if one uses it, he needs to deal with his specific needs in the scope of the Boost modules configuration anyway.

Comment: Ok i can follow the block using approach, but i have a problem with this. The content is within a theme function and not on the page.tpl or so. And it seems i can't access the region from this theme template. I think the blocks are generated after the theme is generated.

Comment: it's my first php and drupal project so it's possible somethings are wrong. But the thing is we are connecting to a service using soap. And when a user is logged in we need to show some button within a theme function. But with full page caching we have some problems, because the button is shown always.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Drupal caches the menu by default, for example. That's usually on every page.

See the cache getters and setters (below). You can make your own by setting a unique cache ID.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_get
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_set